# RouteMap is not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I try to add culture parameter at the first parameter of the url.

If i put `th` at my first parameter, it work fine. `culture` get `th` as its value.
Only problem occurs for `en`. With route debugger, it shows as my following picture.

[image]

I have no idea what wrong... This is crazy.. Rebuild & Clean doesn't help.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's because IIS config file.

I have once create virtual directory name `en` by mistake (From the project setting).

I did disable that setting but the virtual directory remain.

So it needs to delete that item manually in `Documents/IISExpress/config/applicationhost`

Hope this would fix someone.